# Using Vue js component without webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, webpack

Trying to migrate from jQuery web page to VueJs.

I thought wholly rebuild web page to vue-cli based template code might be difficult.

So 1st Step to migrate jQuery to vuejs without webpack. It means all page keep individual pages not SPA. So every single page include vue.js with `<script>` tag.

I stuck with jQuery slider.

Original code seems like `$( ".slider" ).slider({...`.

Converting jQuery's slider to **vue-slider-component** was stuck, cause I don't know how can make static js from vue components.

My expectation is at below.

```
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="vue-slide.js"></script> <-- like this
</head>
<body>
 <vue-slider v-ref:slider :value.sync="value"></vue-slider>
 ...
 <script>
  new Vue({ ...
 </script>
</body>
```

Is stupid idea?

What is the best practice for converting jQuery to vuejs without heavy cost?

Comment: There isn't a 1-to-1 conversion between jQuery and Vue, they work very differently and do entirely different things. You have to decide if you want to have your entire webpage controlled by one main Vue instance, or do you want only certain sections of the webpage to be Vue components; I'm guessing you want the latter, which is not the typical Vue setup.

Comment: Yes, right.  I want the later that only certain sections of the webpage to be Vue components.  My naive idea was migrating single page one by one whenever modification required.

Comment: This article summarizes well your possibilities, I advise you to use option 3 (x-templates): https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/03/24/vue-js-component-templates/ . Your code above doesn't work because you need to initialize the Vue instance and templates before using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now, I often use inline vuejs.  I think that is the good option to migration from legacy code to full SPA.

For example, below code is what I used for migration.

```
<head>
    <script src="lib/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider({
            pauseTime: 3000
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div v-cloak>
            <div id="header">
                <div class="nav" style="display: block;">
...
    </div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    Vue.component('room', {

...

    })

    const app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        component: [
            'room'
        ],
...

    </script>
</body>

</html>
...
```